# guildMemberAdd is not defined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

There seems to be no errors in my code, however when I run this:

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js', 'async');
const bot = new Client();
const cfg = require('./config.json');

bot.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Bot Ready on ${bot.guilds.size} servers`);
bot.user.setActivity('the member list', {type: 3})
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.author.bot || !msg.content.startsWith(cfg.prefix)) return;
const args = msg.content.slice(cfg.prefix.length).split(' ')
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
});
bot.on(guildMemberAdd, member => {
    console.log('User ' + member.user.username + 'has joined the server, adding role')

var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'New Member')

member.addRole(role)

console.log(`Args: ${args}\nCommand: ${command}`) 
});

bot.login(cfg.token);
```

Which is a listener function to add a role whenever a user joins, it throws this error:

```
C:\Users\Sparxo\Desktop\AutoRole\app.js:16
bot.on(guildMemberAdd, member => {
       ^

ReferenceError: guildMemberAdd is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Moneq\Desktop\AutoRole\app.js:16:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I don't see a clear error while revising my code, so I don't know how to fix this. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

The error is showing you that guildMemberAdd isn't defined, meaning that guildMemberAdd doesn't exist in your code, You must use a **string**, not just use the listener name itself, Here is an example:

```
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
```

If however it does not work, You may be using an outdated version of `discord.js`

Answer (score 2):

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
```

I have this working on my bot right now. If this didn't work, you can change "client.on" with "bot.on". Just like some uses "msg" and some uses "message"